# ios filter table data alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm working on a contacts app with 40k+ contacts.

In the list view, I'm showing the index titles A-Z based on the contact data.

Now I need to filter the contacts based on these titles.

My current approach is taking around 10-15 seconds to do the job, I'm wondering if there is an efficient way that could reduce this time.

```
 RLMResults *results = [RealmContact allObjects];
 NSMutableArray *tempData = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (NSString *sectionHeader in titleArr){
    if ([sectionHeader isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
         if (searchQuery.length>0) {
            RLMResults *contactResults = [results objectsWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ == '' or %@ == null)",searchQuery,searchQuery]];
            [tempData addObject:[contactResults sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:@[[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:searchQuery ascending:YES],[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:@"firstName" ascending:YES],[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:@"lastName" ascending:YES]]]];
        }

    }else{
        NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet];

        if ([sectionHeader rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) {

            if (sectionHeader.length>0 && searchQuery.length>0) {
                RLMResults *contactResults = [results objectsWhere:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ BEGINSWITH[c] '%@'",searchQuery,sectionHeader]];
                [tempData addObject:[contactResults sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:@[[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:searchQuery ascending:YES],[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:@"firstName" ascending:YES],[RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKeyPath:@"lastName" ascending:YES]]]];
            }
        }

    }
}

    _dataSource = [tempData copy];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```

the titleArr is sorted array of alphabets #,A,B,C...Z

Where '#' section contains the contacts that has either first name or last name nil.

'A' section contains the contacts that has the first name start with letter 'A'.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *filter*? i.e. does it mean when the user taps 'A' then you switch to another view that just show's the matches that start with A? Or maybe there's a Search Field where the users enter the letter A and the list is then filtered to show just contacts where the first or last name starts with 'A'? Or perhaps CONTAINS[cd] 'A'? I am asking as a database we work with has millions of objects and we're getting filtered data back in about a second.

Comment: No I want to display the contacts in the list view , so the first section is A and that section contains all contacts that first name start with A

Comment: Ok. So where/when does the filtering come in? I can see the filtering in your code and I am reading it correctly, looks like you code is iterating over all titles, A, B, C etc (sectionHeader) and performing a separate query for the searchQuery in each section? So if you are searching for Bob, you start searching in the A section so the query reads objectsWhere['Bob' BEGINSWITH[c] A, which doesn't make any sense. My ObjC is a bit rusty since switching to Swift a few years ago but would't it be simpler to just query all objects that start with Bob? Set me straight here.

Comment: What is `titleArr`? Have you tried profiling your code with the Instruments Time Profiler to see exactly what's taking so long?

Comment: titleArr is an art of Alphabets [A,B,C...Z]  @AustinZ